# Is there any point in merging very old duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, old-questions

I just bumped into two questions from April 2010 which are clearly duplicates.  Should I flag one as a dupe of the other, or are they past the "statute of limitations," so to speak?  I want to help clean up, but don't want to waste mods' time.

If it matters, here are the questions:

- [SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459853/sql-server-management-studio)
- [How to install SQL Server Management Studio 2008 component only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536023/how-to-install-sql-server-management-studio-2008-component-only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if they are exact duplicates, don't worry about how old they are.  Please pick the best one for the canonical and close the other as a duplicate.